# Converting PHYLIP text file to a PNG image

Tags: perl, tree, bioinformatics, scientific-computing, bioperl

Does anyone know how I can convert a [phylip tree format](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/general.html) file in text format to a PNG image programmically in perl?

**Tree file:**

```
(  
B:6.0,  
(  
A:5.0,  
C:3.0,  
E:4.0)  
:5.0,  
D:11.0);
```

I have tried using the [`Bio::Tree::Tree`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Tree::Tree) module but it writes incorrect nodes into an SVG file.

Comment: Are you able to use the module described below?  Does the SVG output produced match your expectations?

Comment: When you try the code below use the SVG ouput before experimenting with PNG :-)  For PNG I'd recommend writing to a filehandle directly from inside the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code produces SVG output on `STDOUT` (I'm not qualified to comment on whether the correct nodes are displayed):

```
use v5.16;     # sets strict and warnings
use Bio::Phylo::Forest;
use Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer;

my $string = '(B:6.0,(A:5.0,C:3.0,E:4.0):5.0,D:11.0);';   

my $forest 
  = Bio::Phylo::IO->parse( -format => 'newick', -string => $string )->first;

my $treedrawer = Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer->new(
           -width  => 800,
           -height => 600,
           -shape  => 'CURVY', # curvogram
           -mode   => 'PHYLO', # phylogram
           -format => 'SVG'
);

$treedrawer->set_scale_options(
           -width => '100%',
           -major => '10%', # major cross hatch interval
           -minor => '2%',  # minor cross hatch interval
           -label => 'MYA',
);

$treedrawer->set_tree($forest);
$treedrawer->set_format('Svg');
print $treedrawer->draw;
```

To produce a PNG image I used the script to direct the SVG output to a file and converted it to PNG with ImageMagick's `convert` utility. It looks like this:

[image: <code>Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer</code> output]

There are facilities for directly creating PNG images with `Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer` as well. To have `Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer` output PNG images you can modify the object's properties using: `$treedrawer->set_format('Png');`

However on my system I get a warning when using the PNG image format:

`WARN Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer::Abstract::_draw_legend [Bio/Phylo/Treedrawer/Abstract.pm: 106] - Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer::Png can't draw a legend`.  I don't think this is a bug. The message would probably be better put as:

`Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer::Png does not support drawing a legend`

If the SVG output from `Bio::Phylo::Treedrawer` is preferable to that of `Bio::Tree::Tree` then you may want to just use that as your data format. You can convert your output file with either an image editor or a perl module that can convert your SVG data to PNG as part of the script.

Comment: It says, Global symbol "$tree" requires explicit package name at line 25.

Comment: @Nari2  typo ... the `->set_tree` method should have been called on  `$forest` not `$tree`

Comment: not only did I miss that typo, I missed the fact that I could have said that I did not see `$forest` because of `$tree` :-)